# How to get primary and secondary screen width and height in objective c for mac osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, screen

I want 4 different function  where each can get me primary screen height, primary screen width, secondary screen height, secondary screen width.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the list of all available screens and their corresponding widths and heights this way:

```
NSArray *screens = [NSScreen screens];

for (NSScreen *screen in screens) {
    CGFloat screenWidth = screen.visibleFrame.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screen.visibleFrame.size.height;
}
```